# Oriented intersection number $I(A, B)$ of $S^2$ and $T^2$ in the oriented product manifold $S^2 \times T^2$

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, intersection-theory, submanifold

In the product manifold $S^2 \times T^2$ of an oriented 2-sphere and an oriented 2-torus, is the oriented intersection number $I(A, B) = \chi(A) \times \chi(B)$ where $A$ is the submanifold $S^2 \times \{p\}$ and $B$ is the submanifold $\{q\} \times T^2$? Or is $I(A, B) = 1$ or $I(A, B) = -1$ since the submanifolds $A$ and $B$ intersect at only one point $(q, p)$ in $S^2 \times T^2$? I'm not sure whether it should be $+1$ or $-1$ but maybe that depends on the choice of orientation on $S^2 \times T^2$.

I think $\chi(A) = I(A, A) = 2$ and $\chi(B) = I(B, B) = 0$ are the respective Euler characteristics of the 2-sphere and the 2-torus using Poincare-Hopf. However, I'm not really sure about how to calculate $I(A, B)$.

Comment: How is this a "followup" question to [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4590387/oriented-intersection-numbers-in-s2-times-t2)? It seems like the exact same question, with some minor refinements. If you want to add some refinements to your previous question, instead of making a new post you should hit the edit button on your old post.

Comment: Of course, if you reverse the orientation of the ambient manifold, the intersection number changes the sign: This is completely general. My suggestion is to reread the definitions and to try to solve these problems yourself.